# Solution instead of writing a bunch of if's

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to write code to let the user pick addition, subtraction, multiplication or division. Once the user has picked one, the program will ask them what difficulty they want, etc. Instead of writing something like:

```
   if (operation.equals("1") || operation.equals("addition")){
            if(level.equals("1")) {

            } else if (level.equals("2")){

            }

        } else if (operation.equals("2") || operation.equals("subtraction")) {
            if(level.equals("1")) {

            } else if (level.equals("2")){

            }
        } else if (operation.equals("3") || operation.equals("multiplication")) {
            if(level.equals("1")) {

            } else if (level.equals("2")){

            }
        } else if (operation.equals("4") || operation.equals("division")) {
            if(level.equals("1")) {

            } else if (level.equals("2")){

            }
        }
```

And so on.

Is there an easier way to write something like this? Instead of writing a bunch of if statements?

Comment: it's not quite clear what you're asking, but how about `switch/case` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Try a switch, for your example it would look something like this.

```
switch(operation) {
   case "1":
   case "addition":
       if(level.equals("1")) {

       } else if (level.equals("2")){

       }
       break;
   case "2":
   case "subtraction":
        ...
       break;
   case "3":
      .
      .
      .
   default:
       ...
}
```

default is used when none of the other cases are true.

Here is a link to a tutorial if the answer wasn't helpful.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could map the string into an enumeration value and the use a switch / case.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class TestMain {
    public enum OPERATOR_TYPE { ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION };

    public static Map<String, OPERATOR_TYPE> lookup = buildMap();

    public static Map<String, OPERATOR_TYPE> buildMap() {
        Map<String, OPERATOR_TYPE> rv = new HashMap<String, OPERATOR_TYPE>();

        rv.put("addition", OPERATOR_TYPE.ADDITION);
        rv.put("subtraction", OPERATOR_TYPE.SUBTRACTION);
        rv.put("multiplication", OPERATOR_TYPE.MULTIPLICATION);
        rv.put("division", OPERATOR_TYPE.DIVISION);

        rv.put("1", OPERATOR_TYPE.ADDITION);
        rv.put("2", OPERATOR_TYPE.SUBTRACTION);
        rv.put("3", OPERATOR_TYPE.MULTIPLICATION);
        rv.put("4", OPERATOR_TYPE.DIVISION);

        return rv;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String opStr = System.console().readLine();
        OPERATOR_TYPE op = lookup.get(opStr.toLowerCase());

        switch (op) {
            case ADDITION:
                System.out.println("Addition");
                break;
            case SUBTRACTION:
                System.out.println("Subtraction");
                break;
            case MULTIPLICATION:
                System.out.println("Multiplication");
                break;
            case DIVISION:
                System.out.println("Division");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```